# Laravel Eloquent - Where clasule with column name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I just realize, that if I have column and connected elequant model (lets say `name` column in `users` table with `User` model), I could call directly `User::whereName('Patrik');`. At least, I have these static methods generated by ide-helper as doc comment. Are these methods relevant? Doc comment also mark Builder or entity itself as return value. How can I know, what entity is returned?
I am using Laravel 5.4 and IDE-heper 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but `User::whereName('Patrik')` will not work until you chain `get()` or `first()`, etc

For example the correct code to return the first entry would be

```
User::whereName('Patrik')->first();
```

Or to return all entries where the name is `Patrik` you would use:

```
User::whereName('Patrik')->get();
```

Comment: I am just confused of generated doc comment, that say it could return Builder (whats make sense for me) or User instance: `* @method static \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|\App\Models\Database\User whereUsername($value)`. I am just asking, what it really return. I also could not find anything about this in Laravel documentation, so I wonder if is OK to use it.

Comment: Try adding ->get() to the end and then regenerate the comments, it may be because you're not initiating the call that it's showing the Builder, as it should always return a collection or null (if no record is found)